# Modifying an existing 4-inch storyboard to work on a 3.5-inch screen

Tags: ios, ios7, uistoryboard

I am programming an application (my first) for iOS 7 using Xcode 5.0.2, and I think I may have made a mistake in designing the story boards on the 4-inch display first, because I want my application to work on both the 3.5 and 4-inch display.

Do I have to create a new story board for the 3.5 inch, or can I use auto layout to configure what I already have? If I can, how do I configure it? I've used auto layout before, but not to support different screen sizes, only for changing from portrait to landscape.

If I have to create a new storyboard, do I have to create new classes for those or can I somehow link to the code I've written?

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout is designed for just this sort of thing. If you have set it up for changing between portrait and landscape, it should Just Work when changing between 3.5 and 4 inches. If not, please post a more specific question!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, as @hatfinch mentioned it will work out of the box. You might have to go modify your constraints to make sure it look okay on 3.5 inch screen.

You can see how your views will look like in 3.5 inch by following ::

1. Select your storyboard.
2. From Editor menu, select " Apply Retina 3.5-inch Form Factor".